# Holding on to an imported file, and then attaching it to an email

Tags: excel, vb.net, outlook

I have created a program that the user will import data from an excel file, that they choose, and then they can send it to an outlook email to send to who it needs to go to.

My question is, how do I code it so the program holds on to that imported excel file and automatically attaches it to the email?

My code is set up to allow the importing of the data, then it dumps the file, and when the user is ready to send the email, they have to re-attach the file to the email.

Here is part of the Import Excel data code:

```
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim objworksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook


    Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog

    ofd.DefaultExt = "xlsx"
    ofd.FileName = " "
    ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    ofd.FilterIndex = "1"
    ofd.Filter = "Excel Files (.xlsx)|*.xlsx| Excel Files(.xls)|*.xls| Excel Files (*.xlsm)|*.xlsm"
    ofd.Title = "Select file"

    If (ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then

        objWorkbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(ofd.FileName)
```

(This is what information needs to be taken and placed where)

The ending of the import data code:

```
 xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False)
            xl.Quit()
        Else

            ofd.Dispose()

        End If
```

---

This is part of my "Send to email" code, instead of the user having to find the same file, I want the program to automatically attach the same file as the imported file. They are from two different functions though, not sure if that's possible.

' Adding Excel File as attachment

```
        Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.DefaultExt = "xlsx"
        ofd.FileName = " "
        ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
        ofd.FilterIndex = "1"
        ofd.Filter = "Excel Files (.xlsx)|*.xlsx| Excel Files(.xls)|*.xls| Excel Files (*.xlsm)|*.xlsm"
        ofd.Title = "Select file"

        If (ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then

            OutlookMessage.Attachments.Add(ofd.FileName)
            OutlookMessage.Display()
        Else
            ofd.Dispose()
            MessageBox.Show("Must attach excel file to proceed")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Email could not be created") 
    Finally
        OutlookMessage = Nothing
        AppOutlook = Nothing
    End Try
End If
```

Comment: Related reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/passing-arguments-efficiently

Comment: ofd.FilterIndex = "1" FilterIndex is an Integer not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can pass variables to procures and you should.

Your declaration would look like this:

```
Public Sub SendMailWithAttachment(ByVal fileName as string)
```

Then your code would use that:

```
OutlookMessage.Attachments.Add(fileName)
OutlookMessage.Display()
```

To use this procedure you would call it like this:

```
SendMailWithAttachment(ofd.FileName)
```

NOTE: The file should not be open when attached. You are just using the filename, not a file object.

Comment: Note that once the `ofd` object has been disposed, `ofd.FileName` will not work. If the e-mail is to be sent after `ofd.Dispose, the filename will need to be saved in a separate string variable.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added the NOTE